# Latex paths (Aurora)

Tags: installing, directory

[image]

The program aurora asks for these, I am not sure I have them installed at all. What am I to do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You need to install a distribution, e.g. MikTeX http://miktex.org/ There are a number of posts on this site on how to do that, please search for them.

Comment: Open a command prompt and type `pdflatex --help` what do you get? If you get lot of details, then you have installed all of it.

Comment: What does this have to do with MS Word?

Comment: @cfr http://elevatorlady.ca It is a plugin for Word.

Comment: @HarishKumar http://pastebin.com/cRFknrC0 can you see this?

Comment: Yes, you have them installed.

Comment: @HarishKumar computer>pdflatex -aux-directory=DIR|||||||||||
pdflatex: The specified directory does not exist.

Comment: What is `DIR|||||||||||`? You should give a proper path.

Comment: |||| I mean the next line, because I cant go to the next line here

Comment: @HarishKumar also having "path value" latex is supposed to work?